# ag-grid filter menu onDisplay function

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am working on a custom filter menu for some columns in ag-grid, where user can click a filter menu icon, which shows a custom component for the filter menu, rather than the default. See below for an example from the documentation, [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#ng2Filtering)

[image: Screenshot from documentation]

I need to perform some action when the filter menu **opens**. *How can i achieve this?*
I thought to use `agInit(params){....}`, however, this initialization function only calls once, when the user first clicks the menu icon...

The only idea I have is to put another component within an `ngIf` and put my initialization logic in there (I assume that when `menuVisible` is true, then ngOnInit within the second component will occur), however that seems awfully inefficient.

```
<div *ngIf="this.params.column.menuVisible">
  <sub-component></sub-component>
</div>
```